# amazon s3 invalid principal in bucket policy

Tags: api, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a new bucket policy in the Amazon S3 console and get the error

> Invalid principal in policy - "AWS" : "my_username"

The username I'm using in principal is my default bucket grantee.

My policy

```
{
  "Id": "Policy14343243265",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SSdgfgf432432432435",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "my_username"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don;t understand why I'm getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the error message says, your principal is incorrect. Check [the S3 documentation on specifying Principals](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingResOpsConditions.html#specifyingPrincipals) for how to fix it. As seen in the [example policies](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html), it needs to be something like `arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root`.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! For better security (I would think) I granted permission to my IAM user using `arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/my_user`

Comment: Also, be aware you can grant permissions to S3 (and other services) directly on an IAM user or group. This is often preferable to permissions at the bucket policy level.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that and using the SDK credentials of that IAM user. Both the bucket policy and the IAM user policy are the same. I'm not sure why I have to specify bucket policies if I just add a grantee with the policies set up. It seems like I'm doing the same thing twice.

Comment: The principal is either your account ID (if you're using your long-term credentials — not recommended), or the ARN of an IAM user (recommended).

Comment: If you've just created your Origin Access Identity, S3 appears to need a few minutes before it accepts it in a bucket policy.

Answer (score 12):

I was also getting the same error in the S3 Bucket policy generator. It turned out that one of the existing policies had a principal that had been deleted. The problem was not with the policy that was being added.

In this instance, to spot the policy that is bad you can look for a principal that does not have an account or a role in the ARN.

So, instead of looking like this:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789101:role/MyCoolRole"
}
```

It will look something like this:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
}
```

So instead of a proper ARN it will be an alphanumeric key like **ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP**. In this case you will want to identify why the bad principal was there and most likely modify or delete it. Hopefully this will help someone as it was hard to track down for me and I didn't find any documentation to indicate this.

Answer (score 7):

Better solution:

1. Create an IAM policy that gives access to the bucket
2. Assign it to a group
3. Put user into that group

Instead of saying "This bucket is allowed to be touched by this user", you can define "These are the people that can touch this".

It sounds silly right now, but wait till you add 42 more buckets and 60 users to the mix.  Having a central spot to manage all resource access will save the day.

Answer (score 2):

The value for Principal should be user arn which you can find in Summary section by clicking on your username in IAM.
It is because so that specific user can bind with the S3 Bucket Policy
In my case, it is arn:aws:iam::332490955950:user/sample ==> sample is the username

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error message when I tried creating the bucket, bucket policy and principal (IAM user) inside the same **CloudFormation** stack. Although I could see that CF completed the IAM user creation before even starting the bucket policy creation, the stack deployment failed. Adding a `DependsOn: MyIamUser` to the BucketPolicy resource fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the error `Invalid principal in policy` in S3 bucket policies, the following 3 steps are the way to resolve it.

**1 Your bucket policy uses supported values for a Principal element**

- The [Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of an IAM user or role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-arns)
- An [AWS account ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html#FindingYourAWSId)
- The string "*" to represent all users

**2 The Principal value is formatted correctly**

- If the Principal is one user

```json
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/user-name1"
}
```

- If the Principal is more than one user but not all users

```json
"Principal": {
  "AWS": [
    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/user-name1",
    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/user-name2"
  ]
}
```

- If the Principal is all users

```json
{
  "Principal": "*"
}
```

**3 The IAM user or role wasn't deleted**

If your bucket policy uses IAM users or roles as Principals, then confirm that those IAM identities weren't deleted. When you edit and then try to save a bucket policy with a deleted IAM ARN, you get the "Invalid principal in policy" error.

---

Read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-invalid-principal-in-policy-error/).

Answer (score 1):

FYI: If you are trying to give access to a bucket for a region that is not **enabled** it will give the same error.

From AWS Docs: *If your S3 bucket is in an AWS Region that isn't enabled by default, confirm that the IAM principal's account has the AWS Region enabled. For more information, see Managing AWS Regions.*

If you are trying to give `Account_X_ID` access to the `my_bucket` like below. You need to `enable` the region of `my_bucket` on `Account_X_ID`.

```
"Principal": {
  "AWS": [
    "arn:aws:iam::<Account_X_ID>:root"
  ]
}
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*",
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

### Why am I getting the error "Invalid principal in policy" when I try to update my Amazon S3 bucket policy?

#### Issue

I'm trying to add or edit the bucket policy of my Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket using the web console, awscli or terraform (etc). However, I'm getting the error message `"Error: Invalid principal in policy."` How can I fix this?

#### Resolution

You receive `"Error: Invalid principal in policy"` when the value of a **[Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)** in your **bucket policy** is **invalid**. To fix this error, review the Principal elements in your bucket policy. Check that they're using one of these supported values:

- **The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) user or role** -- 
  **Note:** To find the ARN of an IAM user, run the `[aws iam get-user][2]` command. To find the ARN of an IAM role, run the `[aws iam get-role][2]` command or just go and check it from the IAM service in your account web console UI.
- **An [AWS account ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html#FindingYourAWSId)**
- **The string `"*"` to represent all users**

Additionally, review the Principal elements in the policy and check that they're formatted correctly. If the Principal is one user, the element must be in this format:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name1"
  }
```

If the Principal is more than one user but not all users, the element must be in this format:

```
"Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                  "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name1",
                  "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name2"
                ]
            }
```

If the Principal is all users, the element must be in this format:

```
{
  "Principal": "*"
}
```

If you find invalid Principal values, you must correct them so that you can save changes to your bucket policy.

#### Extra points!

- [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)
- [Bucket Policy Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

---

**Ref-link:** https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-invalid-principal-in-policy-error/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I've created a bash script to initiate my terraform s3 backend. After a few hours I've decided just to put `sleep 5` after user creation and that made sense, you can notice it at the line 27 of my [script](https://gist.github.com/orihomie/1ec54a4ee4c1cf6e0c955422010f96ca)